# Calculate average for Top n combined with SQL Group By

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, group-by, subquery

This is a very hypothetical example where I am joining two tables (ORDERS and ORDHIST). I'm using MS-ACCESS 2010. I'm trying to write a join or subquery which will return the average for both salespeople for their TOP 2 most recent orders by DATE
**ORDERS**
**SalesPersonID** **OrderID**  **Value**
1                             123        100
1                             124     30
1                              125     55
2                              126     80
2                              127     20
1                              128     45
2                              129     60
2                              130     35

**ORDHIST**
**OrderID**    **Date**
123       22/03/2011
125       25/03/2011
127       29/03/2011
124       24/03/2011
126       26/03/2011
128       30/03/2011
129       30/03/2011
130       01/04/2011

I have the SQL to list records sorted by **SalesPersonID** and **Date**:

```
SELECT Orders.SalesPersonID, Orders.OrderID, Orders.Value, OrdHist.Date 
  FROM Orders 
  INNER JOIN OrdHist ON Orders.OrderID = OrdHist.OrderID 
  ORDER BY Orders.SalesPersonID, OrdHist.Date DESC;
```

```
SalesPersonID OrderID  Value   Date  
1              128       45    30/03/2011  
1              125       55    25/03/2011  
1              124       30    24/03/2011  
1              123      100    22/03/2011  
2              130       35    01/04/2011  
2              129       60    30/03/2011  
2              127       20    29/03/2011  
2              126       80    26/03/2011
```

So I now want to pick the first two rows for each SalesPerson and show just the average of the two to give this Final result I'm looking for:

```
SalesPersonID   LatestAvg
1               50
2               47.5
```

I'm new to writing joins and inner queries and I can't get beyond extracting the average by SalesPerson for all of their orders

```
SELECT Orders.SalesPersonID, Avg(Orders.Value) AS AvgOfValue 
  FROM Orders 
  INNER JOIN OrdHist 
  ON Orders.OrderID = OrdHist.OrderID 
  GROUP BY Orders.SalesPersonID;
```

```
SalesPersonID   AvgOfValue
1               57.5
2               48.75
```

But this isn't filtering on most recent 2 dates within the group so any guidance on how to select within a subquery or create another join will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self join to only get the top 2 rows for each sales person and use a derived table to group those rows for their average.

```
SELECT SalesPersonID, AVG(Value) As AvgOfValue FROM (
  SELECT Orders.SalesPersonID, Orders.Value
  FROM Orders 
  INNER JOIN OrdHist ON Orders.OrderID = OrdHist.OrderID
  INNER JOIN Orders o2 on o2.SalesPersonId = Orders.SalesPersonId
  INNER JOIN OrderHist oh2 on oh2.OrderID = o2.OrderID and oh2.Date <= Orders.Date
  GROUP BY Orders.SalesPersonID, Orders.OrderID, Orders.Value
  HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
) t1 GROUP BY SalesPersonID
```

Comment: Hi FuzzyTree, that was just what I was after. There were some minor typos to correct and I had to add some parentheses to make it Access compatible but I got the answer I was after.

Answer (score 1):

This was the final SQL statement used

```
SELECT SalesPersonID, AVG(Value) As AvgOfValue FROM (
  SELECT Orders.SalesPersonID, Orders.Value 
FROM ((Orders 
INNER JOIN OrdHist ON Orders.OrderID = OrdHist.OrderID) 
INNER JOIN Orders o2 on o2.SalesPersonId = Orders.SalesPersonId)
INNER JOIN OrdHist oh2 on oh2.OrderID = o2.OrderID and oh2.Date >= OrdHist.Date 
GROUP BY Orders.SalesPersonID, Orders.OrderID, Orders.Value 
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
) t1 GROUP BY SalesPersonID
```